# cannot find header search path for xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add a header search path in my project so I go to project > build settings and down to the search path tabs. However there is no option for adding header search paths only framework and library. I am using xcode 4.5 but wondering if that is the problem since if I open another  project ( from the internet) I see header search paths, just not in my project. Ps. I also don't see the user defined search that some people mentioned in other post.

Thank you

Comment: How did you create this project originally? What kind of project is it?

Comment: @matt  An empty project

Comment: I don't believe that. A project created as a _empty_ project would have _no_ build settings.

Comment: iOS or OSX? iOS empty project or Empty Application? Or OSX empty project?

Comment: @matt an empty ios application. Sorry about that

Comment: OK. I just made an empty iOS application and it has 8 build settings under search paths (or 1 if you switch to Basic settings, but I'm sure you didn't do that). The User header search paths is the last one of the 8.

Comment: @matt ah it was under all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the search to find things like this. There's a search box in the upper right corner of the build settings:

[image]